# Streaming large data files received over a websocket as a download

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving file data over a websocket and would like to present this to the user as a download.

One solution would be to build a blob and use `URL.createObjectURL` once the entire file has been received. However I would prefer to start streaming the bytes received immediately to the user (as a standard download) rather than waiting for the whole file to be received first.

This would be especially important for large files.

Comment: You can't do this becouse can't write any data to user's computer. Downloading operation is only managing by browser. For security reasons you can't do this with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As @kodmayna mentions, you can't stream and offer the result as a download.

Three points to note, which affects your progress:

1. Read/Write streams on the native browsers are still experimental/non-standard.
2. Browsers can't access file system via JS (unless you bundle a node application with say, electron as an executable)
3. Read/WriteStreams should be piped (whereas download assumes you have the entire file and will download the file via a request)